# When debugging on an Android device, Video objects sometimes refuse to play a Camera or a NetStream object

Tags: android, flash, video, mobile, air

I have been coding in Flash for a while, though I haven't worked a whole lot on AIR Mobile yet.  That being said, when debugging on an Android device via USB, `Video` objects sometimes work just fine when  `Camera` or `NetStream` objects are attached, and sometimes they refuse to do anything.  In the case of a `NetStream`, the audio is also missing.  Also in the case of a `NetStream` object, if I go to the device's desktop, then come back to the app without ever closing it, then the `Video` object will suddenly start working.

I have two basic methods of reproducing this:

1: For a `Camera`:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class CameraExample extends Sprite
    {
        private var m_cam:Camera;
        private var m_vid:Video = new Video();
        private var m_tmr:Timer = new Timer(1000);

        public function CameraExample()
        {
            stage ? init() : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            function init(pEvent:Event = null):void {
                // support autoOrients
                stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

                m_tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
                m_tmr.start();
            }
        }    

        private function onTimer(pEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if (m_cam = Camera.getCamera())
            {
                m_tmr.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
                m_tmr.stop();

                m_vid.attachCamera(m_cam);
                addChild(m_vid);
                trace("here")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2: For a `NetStream` (this is two programs):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class NetStreamExample1 extends Sprite
    {
        private var m_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        private var m_ns:NetStream;

        private var m_cam:Camera;
        private var m_mic:Microphone;

        private var m_tmr:Timer = new Timer(1000);

        public function NetStreamExample1()
        {
            m_tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
            m_tmr.start();
        }

        private function onTimer(pEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if (m_cam = Camera.getCamera())
            {
                m_tmr.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
                m_tmr.stop();

                m_mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();

                m_nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatusNC);
                m_nc.connect("rtmp://SomeIPAddress/SomeApp/0");
            }
        }

        private function onNetStatusNC(pEvent:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            if (pEvent.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
            {
                m_ns = new NetStream(m_nc);
                m_ns.attachCamera(m_cam);
                m_ns.attachAudio(m_mic);
                m_ns.publish("0", "live");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class NetStreamExample2 extends Sprite
    {
        private var m_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        private var m_ns:NetStream;

        private var m_vid:Video = new Video();

        private var m_tmr:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);

        public function NetStreamExample2()
        {
            stage ? init() : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            function init(pEvent:Event = null):void {
                // support autoOrients
                stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

                addChild(m_vid);

                m_nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatusNC);
                m_nc.connect("rtmp://SomeIPAddress/SomeApp/0");
            }
        }

        private function onNetStatusNC(pEvent:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            trace("m_nc: " + pEvent.info.code);
            if (pEvent.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
            {
                m_ns = new NetStream(m_nc);
                m_ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatusNS);
                m_ns.play("0", "live");

                m_vid.attachNetStream(m_ns);

                m_tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
                m_tmr.start();
            }
        }

        private function onNetStatusNS(pEvent:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            trace("m_ns: " + pEvent.info.code);
        }

        private function onTimer(pEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            trace(m_ns.info.videoBytesPerSecond);
        }
    }
}
```

For the `NetStream` example, run the first part directly out of the IDE, as a desktop AIR app, and run the second part on the Android device through the IDE through a USB cord.  For the FMS, just add a blank app called "SomeApp" without any code.

In the `NetStream` example, I can see comparable amounts being traced for `m_ns.info.videoBytesPerSecond`.  The output when it's working is:

```
m_nc: NetConnection.Connect.Success
m_ns: NetStream.Play.Reset
m_ns: NetStream.Play.Start
m_ns: NetStream.Video.DimensionChange
~15-20k
```

And when it's not working, it's:

```
m_nc: NetConnection.Connect.Success
m_ns: NetStream.Play.Reset
m_ns: NetStream.Play.Start
~15-20k
```

The output is identical in both cases in the `Camera` example.  Either example will either succeed or fail at random.

As stated earlier, in the `NetStream` example, if I run back to the Android device's desktop, then go back to the app without ever closing it, it'll suddenly start working.  In that case, a `NetStream.Video.DimensionChange` event will be logged when I come back to the app.  However this doesn't work for the `Camera` example.

I have tried doing a few things, like recreating the `NetStream` or the `Video`, but stuff like that doens't seem to work.  In general, when this problem is encountered, `Video` objects seem to be useless thoughout the program, as the whole `Video` class appears to be fail internally.

I have tried this on a Galaxy Tab Pro and on my personal LG Access phone.  The phone didn't have any issues with the `Camera` part, but it was definitely vulnerable to the `NetConnection` issue.

Does anyone recognize this or know what is happening?  Does anyone know a good way to fix it?  This does not happen when running it out of the mobile emulators in the IDE.  I'm using Flash Builder 4.7.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will apparently only happen when running in debug mode.  When I switched over to release mode, the problem went away, so something is wrong with Adobe's debugger.  That being said, the AIR SDK I was using at the time I wrote this question was 3.4 (the default for Flash Builder 4.7), so I'm not sure if maybe this has been fixed in later releases.

I am going to post this answer for now and accept it (just because Stack Overflow really encourages having accepted answers), but if someone posts something better and more informative, I'll change which answer I'm accepting.